# C# MVC - Help validating a check constraint from database up through to the view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, sql-server-2008-r2

Starting down at the DB schema I have a CHECK constraint and I'm looking for advice on validating this at the model and view levels as well.

I currently have a validation attribute on the model that mirrors the CHECK constraint, and then the view renders a SELECT list from which the user picks.

**Database:**
ADD CONSTRAINT [myConstraint] CHECK (myField IN ('One', 'Two', 'Three'))

**Model:**
[ValueInList(new[] { "One", "Two", "Three" })]
public string myField { get; set; }

**View:** dynamically render a SELECT from a list of allowed values.

This works, but for those of you keeping track that's **three** copies of the same list, which is just wrong. How should I be implementing this type of scenario?

Answer (score 2):

Check out [MVC Model Validation](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx) and [MVC Custom Validation](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/19/aspnetmvc2-custom-validation.aspx) using your own custom defined attributes.  Basically, you should be able to define your validation logic once on the model/entity level and reuse it in the business tier, web tier, and client-side.

You may also find [Remote Validation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff398048.aspx) useful/helpful.